# How to get position of fingers on touchpad

Tags: touchpad, input, libinput

I want to develop a program which would be able to make use of absolute position of fingers on a touchpad to define custom in-app gestures. I've read that [using raw data from `evdev` is a really bad idea](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2018/07/why-its-not-good-idea-to-handle-evdev.html) as there are many hardware-specific quirks that I'd need to handle and I'd end up rewriting `libinput`.

I would like to get events like *touch begin*, *touch end*, *touch move* for individual fingers, each event including absolute position and ideally pressure of the touch.

So is there a way to get this information from `libinput`? And possibly temporarily disable the default behavior of touchpad during the custom gesture, so that I don't accidentally collide ie. with a gesture to switch workspaces?

When I tried `libinput debug-events` and I got `POINTER_MOTION`, `POINTER_AXIS` and `GESTURE_PINCH_*` events, but without positions of individual fingers. I could definitely use `evdev` but I don't really want to reinvent the weel.